# Search a collection in c#

Tags: c#, search

I'm trying to implament a search engine and wonder what is the best way to perform a search on collection of entities, while entity is an object of data, and the search criteria is changing from time to time: in the number of fields to search by, and in the which fields to search by. for example:
given a collection of itemEntity, (itemEntity is an object contains id, name, gender, age...ect.) I would like to be flexible with search: you can search by name + gender , or you can search by id only and so on.

How to do it? 
p.s.
I'm writing in c#

Comment: [101 LINQ samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) would be a good first destination.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel - use Lucene.net or something else that is already a proven search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Gu [blogged](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) about the dynamic linq expressions, you can find something useful there.

Answer (score 0):

NEVERMIND
THANKS FOR TRYING TO HELP
DID IT BY MY SELF...

MOVE ON ALL SEARCH CRITERIA,(RECIEVE IT IN A DICTIONARY), THEN BY SWITCH CASE - DOING A LINQ SELECT QUERY -> GOT THE RESULTS.